# I want to perform an event actions on <img> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have  structure like this in jquery modal .so i want to perform events on the image either mouseover or click event.
                In the div () black () are increment number at the end of the class name.so how do i perform event actions on this type of classes? pls help me im new to jquery.

```
    <div class="myTag">
      <div class=tag1>
          <img class=close1>
         <div class=tag-bax1>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class=tag2>
         <img class=close2>
         <div class=tag-bax2>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: $('.className').click(function() { ... });

Comment: @RaeenHashemi i tried that way and at the end of classname number is there.so it will increment .so how to identify particuler class name.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean, but for the first image you should write `$('.close1').click(function() { ... });` for the second `$('.close2').click(function() { ... });` and if you want both to take only one function, you should use same classname for both the img objects.

Comment: The situation is i am adding tags i don't how many tags will be there like assume close1 ...close20 as a example .so how to write the single  dynaminc event action for all of them.

Comment: Why don't you use same **`classname`** but different **`id`** s?

Comment: If i use like that second div overwrites the first one.so as like that only last created div is visible to me ,remain div's are created in html but i am not able to see them in view .

Comment: You can use 'startsWith' selector for class but don't, just use a common class for all and then relevant traversing method inside click handler and `this`

Comment: So use `$('img[class*=close]').click(function() { .. });`. This will select every img element which has `close` in their classname.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('img[class*=close]').click(function() {
     ... 
});
```

This will select every **`img`** element which has **close** in their classname.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("img[class*=wl-item]").mouseover(function(){
console.log($(this).attr("class").slice(-1));
});
```